# ActionBarSherlock - How does it creates title on each xml files in layout?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Recently i have successfully implemented the ActionBarSherlock Demos sample in eclipse. But there is something that i am not able to understand it that how this library automatically creates the header with one icon and a text "ActionBarSharelock Demos" in tab_navigation.xml by using merely a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dip">
</LinearLayout>
```

This library is new for me and i am so anxious to know, how this library creates it?

I created a new android project on target api 15 and attach the ActionBarSherlock library to it. then i found that there some of the files are missing from my new android project when i compared it to demos sample project of android. Those files are listed below.

```
1.pom.xml
2.bin/classes.dex
3.bin/jarlist.cache
4.bin/resources.ap_
```

Moreover i got a new error in my activity file on eclipse "R cannot be resolved to a variable."

If you know anything about my problem then please share your views.

Comment: Activity usually inherits it with SherlockActivity. It isn't added in layout xml.

Comment: @ania i said that i saw , tab_navigation.xml in design view on eclipse and found that. I didn't see that thing on emulator.

Comment: In simple, i can say that if i create a xml file in layout direcotory of demo sample of sherlock, then in the design view i can see a tile and an image in my new xml file. This is my question.

Comment: I have done this it was just so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the simplest example:

```
public class Simple extends SherlockActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(R.string.simple_content);
    }
}
```

All you have to do is let your activity inherit one of the Sherlock activites (e.g., SherlockActivity, SherlockFragmentActivity).

You can program the action bar by using the `getSupportActionBar()` method of the SherlockActivity, e.g. to set the title: `getSupportActionBar().setTitle( R.string.my_title );`

Comment: i said that i saw , tab_navigation.xml in design view on eclipse and found that. I didn't see that thing on emulator.

Comment: In simple, i can say that if i create a xml file in layout direcotory of demo sample of sherlock, then in the design view i can see a tile and an image in my new xml file. This is my question.