# ActionBarSherlock - Can i put the ActionBarSherlock library probject in my apps libs directory and attach that library project to my app?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have implemented the ActionBarSherlock by creating two different project, library project and my own android project. Now i am thinking to put library project in my app libs directory and attach this project to my app. Is this logically possible ? If yes, please guide me how can i do this and Is this a good way to put the library project in libs folder?

Comment: I tried to create a new android project under my libs directory but eclipse creates the project outside my app i.e in workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now i am thinking to put library project in my app libs directory and attach this project to my app. Is this logically possible ?

Not at this time. Your library project would be [added as an library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) to your main application project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want tell you that i have implemented actionbarsherlock in this way. I just want to know from you that is this possible to put that library project in libs directory of my app.

Comment: @NaveenChauhan: "i want tell you that i have implemented actionbarsherlock in this way." -- you cannot place a JAR file in `libs/` containing the whole of ActionBarSherlock. ActionBarSherlock is not a JAR. It is an Android library project. You add ActionBarSherlock to an app by means of adding its Android library project to the app's project. Someday, ActionBarSherlock (and other Android library projects) will be distributable as JARs, but that is not the case today.

Comment: May you please solve my problem in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878040/actionbarsherlock-how-does-it-creates-title-on-each-xml-files-in-layout

Comment: Hi, I have almost similar question. I know how to add library project. I just want to know if it's possible to store library project files in  application folder. It's because of repository where application folder is my main folder so I need to put library project folder in it. I tried add library project on same level as src,res but eclipse show some errors.